# Derivatives of exponential and Hermite polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, hermite-polynomials

I interested in computing a closed expression in $m,n\in \mathbb N_0$ for the function
\begin{equation*}
f(n,m) =\left. \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^m \left[e^{-x^2/2} H_n(x)\right]\right|_{x=0}
\end{equation*}
Vi $H_n(x)$ denotes the $n-th$ Hermite polynomial, defined by
\begin{equation*}
H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2}\left(\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x}\right)^n e^{-x^2}
\end{equation*}
I tried to use the recursion relation for subsequent hermite functions and the closed form for the Hermite numbers, but I could not get to any satisfactory result. How shall I proceed?

Comment: It would be good to know your definition of Hermite polynomial. See, there are multiple variants creeping around that differ by a factor of 2 or something.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I added the definition in the body of the question.